# How to setup hyperledger composer on multiple nodes?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I know how to setup hyperleger composer on local system and establish a complete working business network but as per my understanding the concept of blockchain is that all the participants have a copy of ledger and any change is broad-casted and saved on every ledger on the network.
So my question is that lets say if a network has 5 entities A B C D E, and initially code was written on system A and now how that same newtork can be setup on remaining entities?

Answer (score 2):

**Deploying your network**

To deploy your network to multiple hosts I recommend take a look at this documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment

**Adding a new organization**

To add a new organization to your deployed fabric network, there's a tutorial in the documentation:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a question in 2 parts: 1. How to setup a Multi-Entity HyperLedger Fabric.  2. How to setup Hyperledger Composer to work on that Multi-Entity Fabric.

1. Setting up a Multi-Entity from scratch is not a straightforward task a knowledge of certificates, Docker and Networking is a bare minimum skill set.  The [Fabric Documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blockchain.html) is a good place to start with understanding the task.
2. Hyperledger Composer connects to a Fabric via Business Network Cards, which include connection details for the various Fabric Nodes.  This [Multi-Org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html)  walks through a simple example of setting up a Multi-Org Fabric and accessing it with Composer.